# Is there a proof for camerinis algorithm for finding a minimum bottleneck spanning tree?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, correctness-proof

Does someone know a proof for Camerinis Algorithm for finding a minimum bottleneck spanning tree?

To my knowledge its the only algorithm that performs in linear time to solve this task but I cant find a correctness prove for that.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875799/how-to-compute-a-minimum-bottleneck-spanning-tree-in-linear-time

Comment: Have you looked Camerini's original paper "The min-max spanning tree problem and some extensions"? Google Scholar finds a pdf link.

Comment: @pcpthm thanks! just looked it up and read it but it was kind of cryptic for me. By chance, did you get the idea of the proof?